# Do I mark my app as a free or paid app if I have in-app billing?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services

In the Google developer console you can mark your app as free or paid.

I want to make it so it's free to download but you can pay to upgrade the program to a free version (without downloading a separate program). I assume this is done through IAP / in-app billing.

Is it correct to mark my app as a Free app and not a Paid app, even though I want to use in-app billing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark it as a "Free" app in your case, and yes, digital goods/in-app purchases are implemented via Google's In-App Billing service as mentioned [here in the docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should only mark your app as Paid if it requires payment to download. You can put something in the description however to indicate that it requires or offers a subscription.

If you haven’t already, please read through [their guidelines](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?hl=en) for price settings.